# Is anybody using Katalon tool for automation?

Tags: katalon, action-recording

I have 2 questions:

- What is the difference between Selenium builder and Katalon? I think both are same
- Are building scripts used in these tools good enough for passing an interview? I mean: If we can create scripts with these then why we are learning to code?

Comment: it's easy to automate scripts then why we need to learn coding

Comment: Experience with Katalon would be useful in getting a job using it (which I've never seen btw).  But that alone would not translate into skills ready to apply to other tools and situations.  You need more than that to compete with the other applicants.  See the many questions here on how to learn in this area,

Comment: What do you mean by "If we can create scripts with these then why we are using web"?

Comment: I mean why we are learning code? and i see from Katalon tool we can get the code,

Answer (score 1):

Katalon is a GUI which uses Selenium framework. Definitely you will need to get to know some selenium code basics to adequately use the tool. There is no magical tool for test automation where you can write test cases without dabbling into some coding (albeit a lot of products try to sell this).

Answer (score 0):

Katalon Studio is a test automation tool that is based on Selenium. If you know Selenium, using Katalon keywords will be simple to learn since they are just a wrapper around Selenium methods.

Now, you can use Katalon in a variety of ways, one of which is the script mode. That is the "coders" way: you write the test script in Groovy programming language.

Another way is to use web recorder (spy/record mode in Katalon Studio, or Katalon Recorder - a browser add-on). This will give you the script code without you having to do any programming. I'm guessing that is what you are now saying: "If a tool can give me the code, why would I need to learn how to code"?

Well, you don't need to, but it is a very useful skill. And scripts that you wrote yourself would soon be much superior to those made by a web recorder. They tend to be very fragile, have a lot of useless code and are, in my opinion, only good for very simple scripts and for beginners. So, don't be afraid of code, you will soon prefer it to codeless solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes if i get the code by clicking then no need to learn to code, but i observe that it's not correct for simple test scripts they are ok if i go end to end scenarios then it's giving the wrong result

Comment: Yes, as I said, recorded scripts tend to be very brittle. Probably some of the elements' locators are dynamically generated so they change during the next run.